# Running Maven in Jenkins with JFrog Artifactory produces PluginResolutionException

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

The app i am trying to build with Jenkins can't seem to build correctly because plugins/dependencies are missing. I am using JFrog Artifactory in my pipeline and i believe that's what causing this problem. Whenever i use `mvn clean install` it seems to download all dependencies but when I use Jenkins to build the project it generates the following error:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-project
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] newArtifactoryServer
[Pipeline] newMavenBuild
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clone)
[Pipeline] git
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/JFrog/project-examples.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/JFrog/project-examples.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress https://github.com/JFrog/project-examples.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 67bf31bad1fca27577ec0c880a90bd08c959ef8c (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 67bf31bad1fca27577ec0c880a90bd08c959ef8c
 > git.exe branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git.exe branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -b master 67bf31bad1fca27577ec0c880a90bd08c959ef8c
Commit message: "Merge pull request #148 from aaron-tyler/patch-1"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk 67bf31bad1fca27577ec0c880a90bd08c959ef8c # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Artifactory configuration)
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Exec Maven)
[Pipeline] artifactoryMavenBuild
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 3.0.0
Artifactory integration is enabled
[Maven-project] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin/java.exe" -classpath "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\boot\*" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0" "-Dmaven.conf=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\conf" "-DbuildInfoConfig.propertiesFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-project@tmp\artifactory\buildInfo2318213825585143053.properties" -DbuildInfoConfig.artifactoryResolutionEnabled=true "-Dm3plugin.lib=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-project@tmp\artifactory\cache\artifactory-plugin\3.0.0" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-project@tmp\artifactory\classworlds746621898485622615conf" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-project" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f maven-example/pom.xml clean install
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Scanning for projects...
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder - Initializing Artifactory Build-Info Recording
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Reactor Build Order:
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Simple Multi Modules Build                                         [pom]
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Multi 1                                                            [jar]
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Multi 2                                                            [jar]
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Multi 3                                                            [war]
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------< org.jfrog.test:multi >------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Building Simple Multi Modules Build 3.7-SNAPSHOT                   [1/4]
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Reactor Summary for Simple Multi Modules Build 3.7-SNAPSHOT:
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Simple Multi Modules Build ......................... FAILURE [  0.040 s]
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Multi 1 ............................................ SKIPPED
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Multi 2 ............................................ SKIPPED
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Multi 3 ............................................ SKIPPED
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD FAILURE
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Total time:  0.161 s
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: 2019-01-16T00:26:37+01:00
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:22 from/to artifactory-release (Artifactory/libs-release): Cannot access Artifactory/libs-release with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access Artifactory/libs-release using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: Unsupported transport protocol -> [Help 1]
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.RuntimeException: Maven build failed
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.MavenExecutor.execute(MavenExecutor.java:72)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.ArtifactoryMavenBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryMavenBuild.java:78)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.ArtifactoryMavenBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryMavenBuild.java:53)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

The pipeline i am using is as followed:

```
node {
    def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'Artifactory'
    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

    stage ('Clone') {
        git url: 'https://github.com/JFrog/project-examples.git'
    }

    stage ('Artifactory configuration') {
        rtMaven.tool = 'Local Maven' // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
        rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
        rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot', server: server
        buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
        buildInfo.env.capture = true
    }

    stage ('Exec Maven') {
        rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo
    }

    stage ('Publish build info') {
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
}
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-maven-junit-helloworld</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- This configures the compiler to produce Java 8 class files. -->
    <!-- The minimum JDK version installed is 8 of course, but newer JDK releases should work too. -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>

    <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0-M1</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.2.0</junit.platform.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <mockito.version>2.21.0</mockito.version>
    <jacoco.plugin.version>0.8.1</jacoco.plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Testing dependencies. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <!-- Configures the compiler. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <!-- Unit tests are run by surefire. -->
        <!-- Classes under src/test/java called *Test are included automatically. -->
        <!-- Unit tests are run during the test phase. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Integration tests are run by failsafe. -->
        <!-- Classes under src/test/java called *IT are included automatically. -->
        <!-- Integration tests are run during the verify phase. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- <plugin> -->
<!-- Code coverage plugin. -->
<!-- This sets up code coverage for the unit tests, the integration tests, -->
<!-- and the combined coverage of both. -->
<!-- After running a `mvn clean install`, open `target/site/jacoco-both/index.html` in a browser. -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version> -->
        <!-- <executions> -->
          <!-- <execution> -->
            <!-- <id>jacoco-prepare-agent</id> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
              <!-- <goal>prepare-agent</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
          <!-- </execution> -->
          <!-- <execution> -->
            <!-- <id>jacoco-prepare-agent-integration</id> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
              <!-- <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
          <!-- </execution> -->
          <!-- <execution> -->
            <!-- <id>jacoco-report</id> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
              <!-- <goal>report</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
          <!-- </execution> -->
          <!-- <execution> -->
            <!-- <id>jacoco-check</id> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
              <!-- <goal>check</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
            <!-- <configuration> -->
              <!-- <rules /> -->
            <!-- </configuration> -->
          <!-- </execution> -->
          <!-- <execution> -->
<!-- Combine the code coverage statistics generated for the unit and the integration tests. -->
            <!-- <id>jacoco-merge</id> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
              <!-- <goal>merge</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
            <!-- <phase>verify</phase> -->
            <!-- <configuration> -->
              <!-- <fileSets> -->
                <!-- <fileSet> -->
                  <!-- <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory> -->
                  <!-- <includes> -->
                    <!-- <include>*.exec</include> -->
                  <!-- </includes> -->
                <!-- </fileSet> -->
              <!-- </fileSets> -->
              <!-- <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-both.exec</destFile> -->
            <!-- </configuration> -->
          <!-- </execution> -->
          <!-- <execution> -->
            <!-- <id>jacoco-integration</id> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
              <!-- <goal>report-integration</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
          <!-- </execution> -->
          <!-- <execution> -->
            <!-- <id>jacoco-reportboth</id> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
              <!-- <goal>report</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
            <!-- <configuration> -->
              <!-- <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-both.exec</dataFile> -->
              <!-- <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-both</outputDirectory> -->
            <!-- </configuration> -->
          <!-- </execution> -->
        <!-- </executions> -->
      <!-- </plugin> -->

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I saw `url: 'Artifactory'` in the script. Is it a substitution for the question or are you really missing the url there?

Comment: Artifactory is the artifactory server name/d i defined in Jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to JBaruch i realised it should have been:

```
def server = Artifactory.server 'Artifactory'
```

instead of:

```
def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'Artifactory'
```